Как отобразить в инспекторе поля под одним заголовком родителя и наследника?
У меня есть класс-родитель Character и класс-наследник Enemy. У них есть поля, которые нужны для передвижения. Поля Character выглядят так:
#region Настройки передвижения
    [Header("Настройки передвижения")]
    public float MoveSpeed;
    public float SmoothTime;
    #endregion

В Enemy просто дописал поля, которые ему нужны, при этом, добавил такой же [Header("Настройки передвижения")]. Выглядеть в инспекторе стало так:

В Character дальше есть и другое поля и от этого тут есть настройка проверки земли. Проблема в том, что у меня поля, которые по смыслу должны быть вместе (Которые отделены хедером настройки передвижения), в инспекторе отображаются раздельно. Хотелось бы соединить их вместе как-то.

Напишите свое отображение в Инспекторе. https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/editor-CustomEditors.html
